# Installing a program to my server

Tags: invoice, fusion

[image]

Pictures shows that I put on terminal:

sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/fusion_invoice.dev.conf

After that at sitepoint.com says that I need to copy paste below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/fusioninvoice

        ServerName fusion.invoice.dev #change this setting according to your domain name

        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <Directory /var/www/fusioninvoice>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I do not know which path to change.

Help!

Comment: This is not programming related. Try support areas for the application you're trying to deploy. Also, if you're actually running that application, learn about apache and php before putting this in production.

Comment: Ok Viraptor. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the file you mentioned, the Apache config file, add the following code:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/fusioninvoice   # <<< CHANGE THIS PATH TO THE ABSOLUTE PATH ON YOUR SERVER WHERE THE CODE IS STORED

        ServerName fusion.invoice.dev #change this setting according to your domain name

        DirectoryIndex index.php

        <Directory /var/www/fusioninvoice> # <<< ALSO, CHANGE THIS PATH TO THE ABSOLUTE PATH ON YOUR SERVER WHERE THE CODE IS STORED. SAME AS ABOVE
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /

            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope it is clear now :)